# watch console output panel in visual studio while running a XNA game

Tags: c#, console, visual-studio-express, xna-4.0

I'm a visual studio newbie, currently developing a game using VS 2010 express, C# and XNA 4.0 .

I'm trying to debug a little game I'm developing, using a Console.WriteLine call when a certain event occur. Unfortunately when I execute the program the visual studio layout changes and the output panel disappear until the program exits (so I can analyze the output only after the program ends).

I would like to know if it possible and how, to keep the output panel visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whilst in Debug mode, simply show it again by going to **View->Output**

Comment: I can't find View->Output. Is view referred to the menu entry?

Comment: When I hit F5 and am running, View is the 3rd menu along.  Output is listed half way down.

Answer (score 4):

2 things:

1. I output my debug stuff in xna4.0 with

   `System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine("stuff");`
2. To view output just go to `View -> Output` or `Alt+2`

Comment: as far as placing it permanently, have you tried drag and drop the output to the bottom dock?

Comment: I still see nothing in the Debug output window until the program stops. And I find the output under Debug=>Windows=>Output...

Answer (score 1):

If you found this question through a search and you do not see the Output Window under the "View" menu, it is most likely because you are viewing Visual C# 2010 under 'Basic Settings.'  Under basic settings, you can find the output menu as follows:

> Debug -> Windows -> Output

If you want to get out of basic settings, you can change as well:

> Tools > Settings > Expert Settings

And then you will be able to access the Output Window as described in the other answers.